# Viewing Edit Tracking History on Feature Service hosted at ArcGIS Online?

Tags: editing, arcgis-online, versioning, feature-service, archiving

Is there a way to view the edit history of a specific feature service or feature?

I have enabled edit tracking and have been doing fieldwork for 2 weeks now.  I want to see how the data has changed each day I go out.  I want to see how a specific feature has changed each day (I have revisited several points).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to see the state of your data at any time in the past the topic you may want to read up on is [Geodatabase Archiving](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/geodatabase-archiving.htm):

> Archiving in ArcGIS provides the functionality to record and access
>   changes made to all or a subset of data in a geodatabase. Geodatabase
>   archiving is the mechanism for capturing, managing, and analyzing data
>   change.

However, I think you will find (I'm happy to be corrected) that ArcGIS Online does not yet support feature services from feature classes with archiving enabled, or even if it does allow them to be edited it may not support providing views onto their [historical versions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-historical-versions.htm).